# Why is Bayes theorem more popular than the normal definition of P(A|B)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

As everyone knows, the conditional probability of A given B is $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, and Bayes' theorem is derived from that equation to $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.

I'm pretty new to probability, so I'm more than likely missing something, but why has Bayes' theorem become the "popular" equation? It seems to be just a complicated rewriting, and requires more information than the original definition of conditional probability (which Bayes' rule "decomposes" to anyways).

Comment: jaska, in addition to the link provided above, it bears repeating that Bayes' Theorem makes explicit that estimating the probability of $A$ based on new information $B$ (the $P(A|B)$ on the left hand side), *requires* prior existing knowledge of the probability of $A$: (the $P(A)$ on the right side). This makes Bayes' Theorem compelling (or revolting, if that's how your aesthetics run! :) from a philosophical perspective: statements of probability necessarily incorporate subjective belief.

Comment: @Alexis Even dyed-in-the-wool frequentists have no quarrel with Bayes' formula (as stated above) as a theorem in probability theory from a philosophical or any other perspective.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Never said they did.